# Sails.js beforeValidate() emptying value parameter

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm running into an issue with beforeValidate(), and can't find any answers online. My model has two relationship attributes that require id numbers in POSTed data. If a user POST strings instead, they get a validation error. I want to enable the user to POST string data, then inside beforeValidate() use findOrCreate() to find or create the attribute's related model, then overwrite the POSTed data's attribute with the relate model's ID.

I have the following model:

```
attributes: {
    reporter    : { model: 'reporter', required: true },
    location    : { model: 'location', required: true },
    line        : { type: 'boolean', required: true, defaultsTo: true },
    count       : { type: 'int', required: true, defaultsTo: 0},
    composition : { type: 'int', required: true, defaultsTo: 3}
  },

  beforeValidate: function(values, next) {
    if (typeof values.reporter !== 'number') {
        Reporter.findOrCreate({name: values.reporter}).exec(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            values.reporter = data.id;
        })
    };
    next();
  },
```

I'm POSTing this data to the model's create() default blueprint endpoint:

```
{
"location":"Harry's",
"reporter":"tim",
"count":30,
"composition":3,
"line":false
}
```

When I log the above values inside beforeValidate(), I get this:

```
{ location: NaN,
reporter: NaN,
count: '30',
composition: '3',
line: false }
```

When I replace "location" and "reporter" with ID's, I don't get any errors. Why are the string values getting stripped out in the beforeValidate() function?

Answer (score 0):

maybe u need POST(create) to endpoint location model, then POST(create) to reporter model,  and then  POST YOUMODEL/id/reporterID, POST YOUMODEL/id/location ID

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. When I post integers, regardless if a model exists for that primary key, the attribute is still set to the integer when I log the values. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Where in the world are the *built-in* class methods even documented? (`beforeCreate`, `beforeValidate`, etc)